# Performance issue with SQLite database with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am Inserting the data-table into SQLite Database. I am doing like this.
First I Fetch the data with getdata function and insert it into datatable, then with For Each Loop i made the Insert Command and Execute It. I am having 50000 Records it will take 30 Minutes to run.
Please Guide the suitable approach. Here is the Code.

```
Dim xtable As DataTable = getdata("select * from tablename")
Dim str As String = Nothing
For Each r As DataRow In xtable.Rows  ''''HERE IT WILL TAKE TOO MUCH TIME 
     str = str & ("insert into tablename values(" & r.Item("srno") & "," & r.Item("name"));")
Next
EXECUTEcmd(str)   

Public Function getdata(ByVal Query As String) As DataTable
    connectionString()
    Try
        Dim mds As New DataTable
        Dim mycommand As New SQLiteCommand(DBConn)
        mycommand.CommandText = Query
        Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader()
        mds.Load(reader)
        Return mds
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("DB Error", vbCritical, "")
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

 Public Sub EXECUTEcmd(ByVal selectcmd As String)
    Using cn = New SQLiteConnection(conectionString)
        cn.Open()
        Using transaction = cn.BeginTransaction()
            Using cmd = cn.CreateCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = selectcmd
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            transaction.Commit()
        End Using
        cn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

here the Conncection String is:

```
conStr = "Data Source=" & dbpath & ";Version=3;Compress=True; UTF8Encoding=True; PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL; cache=shared;"
```

Comment: Is it the same table in both SELECT and INSERT statements?

Comment: No,  both are different tables....Getting Data from One table and Inserting it to Another

Comment: importing the data from SQLServer to SQLite having 50000 Records at a time. Is there any better solution to do the same task.

Answer (score 1):

Use a stringbuilder to build your string, not string concatenation

```
Dim strB As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(100 * 50000)
For Each r As DataRow In xtable.Rows  
     strB.AppendLine($"insert into tablename values({r.Item("srno")},{r.Item("name")});")
Next
```

Strings cannot be changed in .net. Every time you make a new string VB has to copy everything out of the old string into a new one and add the new bit you want. If each of your insert statements is 100 bytes, that means it copies 100 bytes, then adds 100, then copies 200 bytes and adds 100, then copies 300 bytes, then 400 bytes, then 500 bytes. By the time it has done 10 strings it has made 5.5 kilobytes of copying. By the time it's done 50 thousand strings it has copied **125 gigabytes of data**. No wonder it's slow!

Always use a StringBuilder to build massive strings

--

I'm willing to overlook the sql injection hacking nag for this one, because of the nature of the task, but please read http://bobby-tables.com - you should never, ever concatenate values into an SQL as a way of making an sql that has some varying effect.

This entire exercise would be better done as this (pseudocode) kind of thing:

```
Dim sel as New SQLiteCommand("SELECT a, b FROM table", conn)
Dim ins as New SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO table VALUES(:a, :b)", conn)
ins.Parameters.Add("a" ...)
ins.Parameters.Add("b" ...)

Dim r = sel.ExecuteReader()

While r.Read()
  ins.Parameters("a") = r.GetString(0)
  ins.Parameters("b") = r.GetString(1)
  ins.ExecuteNonQuery()
End While
```

That is to say, you minimize your memory by reading rows one at a time out of ther edaer and inserting them one at a time in the insert; the insert command is prepared once, you just change the parameter values, execute it, change them again, execute it ... It's what parameterized queries were designed for (as well as stopping your app getting hacked when someone puts SQL in your variable, or even just stopping it crashing when you have an person named O'Grady

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must refactor your code like this:

```
Dim xtable As DataTable = getdata("select * from tablename")

Using cn = New SQLiteConnection(conectionString)
    cn.Open()
    Using transaction = cn.BeginTransaction()
        Try
            Using cmd = cn.CreateCommand()
                cmd.Transaction = transaction
                For Each r As DataRow In xtable.Rows  ''''HERE IT WILL TAKE TOO MUCH TIME 
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tablename values(" & r.Item("srno") & "," & r.Item("name") & ")"
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
            End Using
            transaction.Commit()
        Catch ex As Exception
            transaction.Rollback()
        End Try
    End Using
End Using

Public Function getdata(ByVal Query As String) As DataTable
    connectionString()
    Try
        Dim mds As New DataTable
        Dim mycommand As New SQLiteCommand(DBConn)
        mycommand.CommandText = Query
        Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader()
        mds.Load(reader)
        Return mds
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("DB Error", vbCritical, "")
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Instead of concatenate an possible giant string, wrap all your inserts into a single transaction, like above. This will reduce the memory used and also make sqlite perform faster.

Comment: the above code works but when i have do it without for loop. it remains very slow.          
                   Using cmd = cn.CreateCommand()
                          cmd.Transaction = transaction
                          cmd.CommandText = sqlstring                                            
                           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                   End Using.                                                                                                                                               This sqlstring having 50000 Recods.